# Content Scroll to Bottom Not Working

Tags: ionic3

I am Developing App in ionic. when load page scrollToBottom not working.

Html section

```html
<ion-content #content>
</ion-content>
```

TS Section

```ts
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PersonalChatPage');
    this.content.scrollToBottom();
}
```

Comment: any errors in console? what does not working mean?

Comment: No error in Console.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a delay will fix your issue.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PersonalChatPage');
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(()=>{that.content.scrollToBottom();},200); 
}
```

And another thing as your code has **#content** tag like below:

```
<ion-content #content></ion-content>
```

Then you can write like:

```
@ViewChild('content') content: Content;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `scrollToBottom()` code may run before the DOM is completely updated.

Several solutions based on reacting to DOM/Template to execute the scrolling can be tried.

#### First Solution

The best one that i have found was in this article by [josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/automatic-scroll-to-bottom-chat-interface-with-mutation-observers-in-ionic/)

To resume it:  One could use a Mutation Observer to execute the scroll only when a certain DOM event has triggered.

Here is some code to illustrate it.

```
// To get Typescript completion for Ionic 4 use: 
// import { IonContent } from '@angular/core'
// @ViewChild(Content) contentArea: IonContent;


@ViewChild(Content) contentArea: Content;
// list in the template to observe
@ViewChild(List, {read: ElementRef}) chatList: ElementRef;

// MutationObserver doesn't need to be imported
private mutationObserver: MutationObserver;

ionViewDidLoad(){

    // Code to be executed on event
    this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        this.contentArea.scrollToBottom();
    });

    // the Element that will be Observed
    this.mutationObserver.observe(this.chatList.nativeElement, {
        childList: true
    });

}
```

More info about [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) at Mozilla.
Its browser compatibility is very good.

#### Second Solution

I haven't personally tried it, but another very interesting alternative can be found in this answer by [mhartington](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/open-page-already-scrolled-at-bottom-chat-app/77634/4) from the Ionic Team.

Here is the code:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let last = last">
      {{ item }}
      {{ last ? callFunction() : '' }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>


export class Page2 {
  public items: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        this.items[i] = i
      }
    }, 300)
  }
  callFunction(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
}
```

So the idea is to call `this.content.scrollToBottom()` only once the last item is created on the template. Using index, this would give the power to automatically scroll to any of the elements, although i don't see the use at this moment.

As for the argument that it isn't good to directly manipulate the DOM in Angular: There is no manipulation, just reacting in the component to a DOM event...

Answer (score -1):

don't use the garbage scrolling methods from your framework I have the same problem with framework ionic, instead use standard .scrollIntoView() it works nicely...

I set up two dummy hidden divs, top and bottom around my "content" like so

```
<div id="QV_Top">TOP</div> 
... your actual content here
<div id="QV_Bottom">BOTTOM</div>
```

then fixed my scroll helper methods like so:
[image]

finally the actual scroll to id follows:
[image]